# Rails 7 controller won't recognize format.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app using Rails 7 and Ruby 3.2.1, I have the following controller that is responsible for serving data to a Stimulus controller. The data is serialized using `::DtfsOrders::OrderItemSerializer` to display in a table. Unfortunately, nothing is being displayed, and I suspect there may be an issue with the controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/MethodLength
    skip_policy_scope
    authorize(:order_item, :index?)

    @order_items_params = params.permit(:page).merge(limit: OrderItems::ListComponent::LIMIT)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @order_item_list = fetch_order_items(@order_items_params.merge(limit: 1).to_h)
      end
      format.json do
        render json: fetch_order_items(@order_items_params.to_h)
          .serialize(::DtfsOrders::OrderItemSerializer, scope: view_context)
          .as_json
      end
    end
  rescue ::DtfsOrders::Error => e
    redirect_to root_path, alert: api_error_message(e)
  end

  private

  def api_error_message(error) = I18n.t('api_error', error: error.message, scope: 'order_items')
  def fetch_order_items(params) = FactoryBot.build(:dtfs_orders_order_item_list, :with_next_page, total_count: 1)

  def client = @client ||= ::DtfsOrders::Client.with_account(current_account)
end
```

When I put `binding.pry` into a format block:

```
      format.json do
        binding.pry
        render json: fetch_order_items(@order_items_params.to_h)
          .serialize(::DtfsOrders::OrderItemSerializer, scope: view_context)
          .as_json
      end
```

It doesn't stop, which means it didn't recognize this request, which is weird. Below is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Core::Engine, at: '/'

  resources :order_items, only: %i[index]
end
```

what did I missed here?

**[EDIT]**
Here is my stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';

import * as AgGrid from 'ag-grid-community';

import {
  DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS,
  buildColumnDefs,
  GridDatasource,
  updateColumnPositionsInCookies,
} from 'core/utils/grid';

const columnOptions = {
  columnDefs: {
    order_reference: { cellClass: 'font-mono', cellRenderer: 'flexCellRenderer', sortable: false },
    order_date: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 300, sortable: false },
    description: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 300, sortable: false },
    quantity: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 300, sortable: false },
    amount: {
      cellClass: 'ag-right-aligned-cell font-mono', maxWidth: 200, sortable: false,
      headerClass: 'ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase bg-gray-100'
                   + ' ag-focus-managed ag-right-aligned-header' },
    currency: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 100, sortable: false },
    vat: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 100, sortable: false },
    actions: { cellClass: 'ag-right-aligned-cell font-mono', maxWidth: 120, sortable: false, withoutHeader: true },
  },
  cookiesName: 'order_items_columns_positions',
  defaultSorting: [
    'order_reference',
    'order_date',
    'amount',
    'quantity',
    'currency',
    'vat',
    'description',
    'actions'
  ],
};

function buildGrid(gridElement) {
  console.log('Building grid with element:', gridElement);

  const {indexUrl, paginationPageSize, i18nJson} = gridElement.dataset;

  console.log('indexUrl:', indexUrl);
  console.log('paginationPageSize:', paginationPageSize);
  console.log('i18nJson:', i18nJson);

  const options = {
    ...DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS,
    cacheBlockSize: paginationPageSize,
    maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 2,
    columnDefs: buildColumnDefs(columnOptions, i18nJson),
    datasource: new GridDatasource({ indexUrl }),
    onColumnMoved(params) { updateColumnPositionsInCookies(columnOptions, params) },
  };

  console.log('Options:', options);

  return new AgGrid.Grid(gridElement, options);
}

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const gridElement = this.element.querySelector('#order_itemsGrid');

    if (gridElement) {
      this.gridObject = buildGrid(gridElement)
    }
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.gridObject) {
      this.gridObject.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using get and post from request.js? In any case, you need to set the request type to application/json

Comment: @RubyRacer excelent question - I've no clue. Added a stimulus controller, maybe that might be helpful.

Comment: This is very library specific. I'd suggest you go through the documentation, see it there's a relative data type option

Comment: When debugging XHR it's usually better to look at the network tab in the browser to see what it's sending and the Rails log to see how it's being processed by the Rack stack before it hits your application.